# Can I make a circle shape out of my inset shape?

Tags: edit-mode

Can I make a circle from the inset shown below?
I want to create a circle so I can extrude it inwards.

Here is the file just in case: [image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Remove the face, create a 32 vertex circle:

[image]

Fill with consecutive <kbd>F</kbd>:

[image]

Fill the faces, extrude inwards, etc:

[image]

Comment: Ah yes! How does the consecutive F work?

Comment: Select 2  opposote vertices, press F, then press F and F again and it should work in the latest versions of Blender

Comment: I have version 3.1 - it doesn't seem to work for me

Comment: Ok so you may need to enable the addon called F2

Comment: Ah yes great! Thank you